# What is the meaning of these stencils, usually found on military planes?

Tags: military, aircraft-maintenance, feature-identification, aircraft-marking

I am wondering what these markings (which I found both in the French Super Etendard and in the British Tornado) indicate? They may be something relevant for the maintenance crews.

[image: Vertical stabiliser of a Super Etendard modernise, showing two types of stencils, one looks like a hook, the other a horizontal line with two bulges]

Comment: The top one indicates that it is safe to hang your uniform jacket from the winglet. :)

Answer (score 61):

The sine wave sign indicates an access panel for electronics. Two examples:

> [image]
> [sbap.be](http://www.sbap.be/aircraft/f104g/f104g.htm); electronic comp. access

> [image]
> [sbap.be](http://www.sbap.be/aircraft/f104g/f104g.htm); electrical bay access

The handle shape indicates a nearby anchor point for hoisting the plane.

---

Here's a collection:

> [image]
> [scottbouch.com](https://scottbouch.com/English-Electric-Lightning-technical-resource.html)

In your photo, the forward facing protruding part is a forward radar warning antenna.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by listing the picketing point (upper symbol) and describing what it is.

Comment: According to the diagram in the answer, the hook on a bar isn't a picketing point but a slinging/hoisting point.  I don't know enough about maintenance to know if they're colloquially interchangeable.  In any case, they're on civil aircraft too, not just military.

Comment: @user: upper symbol was already described – see previous comment. Anyway, picketing point is simply tie-down point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and for the helpful images.

Comment: Two semicircles don't look like a sine wave to me... :[]

Comment: It's fascinating to think that there must presumably be people with enough business accessing aircraft electronics who nevertheless require markings to remind them where they are...

Comment: @TomW: Aircraft are serviced by more than one team, and *each team services different types,* e.g. fueling teams in an air force. This is easier than mistaking an access point and then opening them all :)